# Error Message in a Case Statement

Tags: plsql

I have written the following statement which doesn't work because of the `In` clause i've added.  Can someone help suggest a workable solution?

What I want to do is measure the min/max values of grades for each record key.  Some have more than one grade so thats why I've added the `In` clause so it will factor this?

```
case when MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency")=MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency") 
IN (People." Record Key") then 'y' else 'n' end
```

The data in the table looks like this:

RecordKey  Version   Grade

165          2009      1

165          2012      2

175          2009      1

189          2012      1

200          2009      2

200          2012      1

Comment: Sorry, but can't understand your requirements.  Can you give an example of input and required output?

Comment: I have created a simple report which looks at grade change across two years 2009 and 2012.  In the report there are 3 columns: Record Key, Version and Grade. A Record Key can appear on multiple lines if their Grade has changed between 2009 and 2012 (Version) or if they are present in both years.  I want a statement that will assess each row for each Record Key and add a Group Marker against them, so if the Grade has changed then has it increased/decreased or has it stayed the same?

Comment: Can you update your question and show what this report looks like?

Comment: I've added in the 3 columns from the report and some data.  I just want the extra column to say increase, decrease, stayed the same etc

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Boolean condition:
"MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency")=MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency")" in your when, so you cannot also do an IN clause too.

Also when you use the IN clause in the parenthesis you have to put values not table columns.

Maybe you need something like:

```
case
when MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency")=MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency") AND MIN("Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency") IN (one or more values...) then 'y' 
else 'n' 
end
```

**Second answer...**

It's a little more complex, as it uses analytical functions.

Take a look below:

```
select RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR, GRADE,
case
  when GRADE_PREV = 0 and GRADE_NEXT >= 0 then 'Stayed the same'
  when GRADE_PREV = 0 and GRADE_NEXT > 0 then 'Stayed the same'
  when GRADE_PREV > 0 and GRADE_PREV < GRADE then 'increased'
  when GRADE_PREV > 0 and GRADE_PREV > GRADE then 'decreased'
  else null
end as grade_change
from
(
  select RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR, GRADE
  ,LAG(GRADE, 1, 0) over (partition by RECORDKEY order by RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR) as GRADE_PREV
  ,LEAD(GRADE, 1, 0) over (partition by RECORDKEY order by RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR) as GRADE_NEXT
  from PLCH_GRADES
)
order by 1,2
```

**Third answer...**

Here it is, now integrating your "original" query:

```
select RECORDKEY, CALENDAR_YEAR, HEADCOUNT, GRADE,
case
  when GRADE_PREV = 0 and GRADE_NEXT >= 0 then 'Stayed the same'
  when GRADE_PREV = 0 and GRADE_NEXT > 0 then 'Stayed the same'
  when GRADE_PREV > 0 and GRADE_PREV < GRADE then 'increased'
  when GRADE_PREV > 0 and GRADE_PREV > GRADE then 'decreased'
  else NULL
end as GRADE_CHANGE
from
(
  select RECORDKEY, CALENDAR_YEAR, HEADCOUNT, GRADE
  ,LAG(GRADE, 1, 0) over (partition by RECORDKEY order by RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR) as GRADE_PREV
  ,LEAD(GRADE, 1, 0) over (partition by RECORDKEY order by RECORDKEY, VERSION_YEAR) as GRADE_NEXT
  from 
  (
    select 
      PEOPLE."Record Key" as RECORDKEY, 
      CALENDAR.year as CALENDAR_YEAR, 
      "Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency" as GRADE, 
      "Fact - People".HEADCOUNT  
    from test 
    where location = 'NI'
    and PEOPLE."Status Group" = 'CURRENT'
    and PEOPLE."Headcount Marker" in ('Paid', 'Unpaid')
    AND Calendar.Year IN ('2009', '2012') 
  )
)
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but this wont work.  It would be impossible to state the values in this instance due to the volumes.  I just want to check each grade against each record key, and if more than one grade appears for a record key then assess them and say whether they have increase, decreased etc.  If one grade appears then it would say stayed the same

Comment: Thanks again.  I can see what you are doing but I can't seem to fit my original code around it.  Also I am using Answers in OBI, by going into the advanced tab.  This should work in here?  My original code is: SELECT People."Record Key" saw_0, Calendar.Year saw_1, "Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency" saw_2, "Fact - People".Headcount saw_3 FROM Test WHERE (Location = 'NI') AND (People."Status Group" = 'CURRENT') AND (People."Headcount Marker" IN ('Paid', 'Unpaid')) AND (Calendar.Year IN ('2009', '2012')) ORDER BY saw_0

Comment: Apologies I have not been able to try this code, but once I do I will let you know how it runs.